# Splitting Dataset Computations among worker threads in C++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I have a **2D Vector Dataset** with 1500 rows and I want to perform a computationally expensive operation on each row. I want to utilize multiple threads to accomplish this so that this executes as fast as possible.

I cant find any definitive solutions on the internet as to how this should be solved. I thought of making a thread for each row but that seems very inefficient since 1500 threads will take up a lot of unnecessary resources. Thus, it would be best to make **6 worker threads**(My PC has 6 cores) and split the work.

```
//Computationally expensive function
double Loss(vector<double> input,vector<double> expectedOutput);

//This Calculates the Loss of all the 1500 rows in the 2D Vector and returns their average
double TotalLoss(vector<vector<double>> inputs,vector<vector<double>> expectedOutputs);

//TBD: Implement TotalLoss using multipel threads
double MultiThreadedTotalLoss(vector<vector<double>> inputs,vector<vector<double>> expectedOutputs);
```

I tried to use **std::thread** to implement the different threads but cant figure out how to split the work into 6. I thought of making 6 different vectors and dividing the original Vector but don't know if that's the best possible approach.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Read about thread pools. Basically, the idea is you treat every row as a "task" or "job" for your pool. You initialize the pool with some number of worker threads which all read from a synchronized queue. They keep pulling a job off the queue until there are none left. At that time, they either go to sleep (waiting for the queue to signal that more jobs are available) or they terminate (if this is a one-off operation). Now fill up your queue with tasks and let the threads do their thing. Once all threads have signalled that they're finished processing, the work is done.

Comment: Just as a separate point, you should be aware that your function signatures at present are accepting all their data _by value_, meaning that your vectors will be copied every time you make a function call. You should pass the data by reference instead. And if thread pooling seems to complicated, there are parallel processing libraries (Intel TBB and OpenMP are two popular ones) that can do the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback... I'll be sure to read up about threadpools

Comment: Do you have a small example of a threadpool though?

Comment: For fun, I knocked up a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/eTcjfjvTG) with a moderately flexible thread pool that has some commonly-needed functionality such as: wait for all tasks to complete, suspend/resume processing, and abandon remaining tasks.

Answer (score 1):

Given that you already have a function to compute the loss for one row, I'm going to guess that your `TotalLoss` function would look something like this:

```cpp
using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;

double TotalLoss(Matrix const &inputs, Matrix const &expected) {
    double ret = 0.0;

    for (int i=0; i<inputs.size(); i++) {
        ret += loss(inputs[i], expected[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Assuming that's reasonably accurate, a multithreaded version could look something like this:

```cpp
using Matrix = std::vector<std::vector<double>>;

double MultithreadedTotalLoss(Matrix const &inputs, Matrix const &expected) {
    double ret = 0.0;

    #pragma omp parallel for reduction(+:ret)
    for (int i=0; i<inputs.size(); i++) {
        ret += loss(inputs[i], expected[i]);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

One extra line for the #pragma, and off you go. For that matter, even the `reduction(+:ret)` part of that is optional, though it can help efficiency a fair amount (it basically tells the compiler/library to keep a per-thread accumulator, then add those together at the end, rather that having the threads fight over access to a single variable as they're running). If `loss()` is really expensive, this probably won't make much difference though.

This has a few advantages over doing the threading explicitly. The obvious one is that it's pretty simple compared to writing all the threading code explicitly. Less obviously, but often nearly as important is that it can/will automatically find (and use) the number of cores available, so it'll use the six you have, but if you run it on a machine with, say, 128, it'll automatically use all of them. In the long term, it also has an advantage in continuing to keep the basic algorithm involved easy to find, easy to read, etc. Explicit multithreading can pretty quickly end up dominated by the thread management "stuff", so it's almost hard to find the code that does the real work.

The big disadvantage is lack of flexibility. For code like this, OpenMP can work really well--but for some other situations, it's much more difficult to apply.

Comment: I suppose I have to use the OpenMp library for this to work right?

Comment: Since my program doesn't have a lot of multithreading isn't it better to just stick to a manually implemented threadpool? Maybe not though coz this looks way simpler...

Comment: @SoumishDas: You have to enable the compiler's OpenMP support to use this (e.g. `-fopenmp` with gcc or clang, or `-openmp`with Microsoft). It's not really a question of how *much* you use multithreading so much as *how* you use multithreading. If your use all follows the same pattern of executing iterations of a loop in parallel, I'd stick to OpenMP. If you have other patterns of use, then there's a lot bigger chance you'll want to do something else.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below ThreadPool example. It's not perfect, but should give you an idea :-)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <queue>
#include <vector>
#include <atomic>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <functional>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std::chrono_literals;

class ThreadPool
{
public:
    ThreadPool(int no_of_threads) : m_pool(no_of_threads)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < no_of_threads; i++)
        {
            m_pool[i] = std::thread(&ThreadPool::thread_func, this, i);
            m_pool[i].detach();
        }
    }

    void add_task(std::function<void(int)> task_fn)
    {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(m_mutex);
        m_task_queue.push(task_fn);
        m_cv.notify_all();
    }

    void stop_processing()
    {
        m_stop_all_threads = true;
    }
private:
    void thread_func(int thread_id)
    {
        while (!m_stop_all_threads)
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lck(m_mutex);
            // wait for some task to be added in queue
            if (!m_cv.wait_for(lck, 100us, [this]() { return !m_task_queue.empty(); }))
                continue;
            // pick up task, update queue
            auto fn = m_task_queue.front();
            m_task_queue.pop();
            lck.unlock();
            // execute task
            fn(thread_id);
            // std::this_thread::sleep_for(1us);
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::thread> m_pool;
    std::atomic<bool> m_stop_all_threads{false};
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_cv;
    std::queue< std::function<void(int)> > m_task_queue;
};

int main()
{    
    ThreadPool pool(5);

    int i = 0;
    while (i < 100)
    {
        pool.add_task([x = i](int id) { std::cout << "This is task " << x << " in thread " << id << '\n'; });
        i++;
    }
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(5ms);
    pool.stop_processing();
}
```

Currently, the `m_task_queue` is expecting a `std::function<void(int)>`. You can change it to whatever signature you require.